# ExtJS 5.0 - overriding initComponent to customize components

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, overriding

I'm trying to access the form's components in an override to customize them. I have confirmed `itemId == 'name'` or `itemId == 'description'`, but this code just pulls up `undefined`.

```
Ext.define('Products.overrides.view.NewProduct', {
    override: 'Products.view.NewProduct',
    initComponent: function() {
        // Set up first
        this.callParent([]);
        // Revise the maximum lengths
        this.getComponent('name').maxLength = 50;
        this.getComponent('description').maxLength = 250;
    }
});
```

The types of `name` and `description` are single line text entry, but they may be changed to something else. I have tried all kinds of approaches to get these components without success. I have seen `query` suggested, but I may not be able to guarantee the component types, so not sure if this is useful.

This shouldn't be so difficult, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your code should work, see [`this fiddle`](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s2t). Your problem lies elsewhere, perhaps the components you are looking for are simply not there or not configured properly? Post a full example or better a fiddle.

Comment: Thank you. Buddy's direction on how to use `query` solved it. The original form was designed by a third party with the code being complex and non-standard, so not surprised some methods don't work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve using this:

```
val components = this.query('*[itemId=name]');
```

Then access as the first element:

```
components[0].maxLength = 50;
```

The asterisk lets you match with any component type. You might want to check the length of the array. If it's more than one, then the item ID isn't unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding the initComponent function, you have to call the `callParent()` function.

```
Ext.define('Products.overrides.view.NewProduct', {
    override: 'Products.view.NewProduct',
    initComponent: function() {
        // Set up first
        this.callOverridden();
        // Revise the maximum lengths
        this.getComponent('name').maxLength = 50;
        this.getComponent('description').maxLength = 250;
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

ExtJS 5.0 Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-initComponent

Comment: Nope, `callOverridden` will call the original `initComponent` which will in turn do `callParent` if needed.

Comment: @DrakeES Anyways, i see in the docs that `callOverriden` is currently deprecated, but my answer still doesn't resolve the problem of the post >.< https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-callOverridden

Comment: Yes the best would be to call `callParent` *instead* of `callOverriden`, but definitely not both of them! In your example the parent's `initComponent` is effectively called twice.

Comment: Thank you, have changed the first line to `this.callParent([]);`